# Number of ways to put $n$ objects with $k$ distinguishable groups into sets of size $a$, $b$, and $c$ $(a+b+c = n)$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have $n$ objects in $k ≤ n$ distinguishable groups, for the case of $k = n$ (all objects distinguishable), I believe the number of ways to choose, without replacement, $a$ objects, then $b$ objects, then $c$ objects (where $a + b + c = n$) is $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$. I think in the case of $k = 1$ (all objects indistinguishable), the answer is just 1 (?). I'm wondering how this can be extended for $1 < k < n$? Does the solution change whether $a, b, c > 0$ or if one of them equals 0?

Comment: So you have a strip of length $n$ and you have $k$ different colors and you wanna know in how many ways can you color the strip? If you have $1$ color, yes, just one way. If you have $3$ colors and you want $a$ of the first, $b$ of the second and $c$ of the third, yes it is $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}.$

Comment: What if I have say, n = 9 balls with k = 8 distinct groups (such that two of the balls are indistinguishable), and I want to find the number of ways to choose/group them into 3 sets of 3 (a = b = c = 3)?